# Matching the first instance of a sub-string to a regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match everything in a string up to the ending of a multi-line comment using python's re module.

the string I'm having trouble with at the moment is:

```
i = 333;        ******************/       */
```

The search that I'm performing on the string is as follows:

```
tempLine = re.search(r'.*\*/(.*)', line, flags=0).group(1)
```

I was expecting the search function to match any amount of characters up to the first occurrence of `*/` .

I wanted to save everything after the first `*/` using the group I added to the re, and save it in the variable tempLine.

The regex match object ended up as follows:

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 41), match='i = 333;     *****************/       */'>
```

And the group ended up as:

```
""
```

Meaning that the regular expression matched everything up to the `*/` at the end of the string, rather than the first `*/` that occurred after the series of asterisks.

How do I make the re match everything up to the first occurrence of `*/` instead?

Comment: You don't double backslashes inside a raw string.

Comment: You need to use a non-greedy quantifier, otherwise it goes to the last occurrence.

Comment: Why not matching the multiline comment as a whole?

Answer (score 1):

Because your target is a fixed string, and because you are looking for exactly the first match, you might consider using a non-`re` function such as [`str.partition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20partition#str.partition) instead.

This will be faster, since it doesn't need the overhead of regular expression processing.

Answer (score 0):

This expression,

```
[^/]*/\s+(?=\*/)
```

with `re.search`, `re.match`, or `re.findall` might be also working OK.

#### Test

```
import re

string = "i = 333;        ******************/       */"

print(re.search(r"[^/]*/\s+(?=\*/)", string, re.DOTALL).group(0))
print(re.match(r"[^/]*/\s+(?=\*/)", string, re.DOTALL).group(0))
print(re.findall(r"[^/]*/\s+(?=\*/)", string, re.DOTALL))
```

#### Output

```
i = 333;        ******************/       
i = 333;        ******************/       
['i = 333;        ******************/       ']
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/0KorZ2/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/0KorZ2/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

Answer (score 0):

You could use [re.search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) with:

```
[^/*]+\*+/(.*)
```

**Explanation**

- `[^/*]+` Match 1+ times any char except `/` or `*`
- `\*+/` Match 1+ times `*` followed by `/`
- `(.*)` Capture **group 1** match any char except a newline 0+ times (Or `(.+)` for 1+ times)

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/phqBoq/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/qiYc2T)

For example

```
import re

regex = r"[^/*]+\*+/(.*)"
test_str = "i = 333;        ******************/       */python "
matches = re.search(regex, test_str)

if matches:
    tempLine = matches.group(1)
    print(tempLine)
```

Result

`*/python`

Answer (score -1):

You can do that with this regex `(.*?)\*/`

`(.*?)` gets n characters into group 1, ? makes it non greedy, meaning it will stop matching when the next rule is a match.
`\*/` gets */

```py
line = 'i = 333;        ******************/       */'
tempLine = re.search(r'(.*?)\*/', line, flags=0).group(1)
print(tempLine) # i = 333;        *****************
```